# My computer has windows 7 professional.I created a virtual machine of Deepin12.06 in virtualbox. Unable to copy from guest to host?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to copy files from a [deepin linux](http://www.linuxdeepin.com/index.en.html) virtualbox machine to my windows 7 host machine?

I have not found any good answers yet.Please I need a tutorial or screenshot will be good.

Comment: Could you add in more details? What's your networking setup - nat or bridged?

Comment: You likely haven't installed guest additions yet. It is required for copy and paste to work (shared folders)

Comment: I have installed guest additions on my deepin guest machine. @spuder

Comment: @JourneymanGeek its NAT setup. i am using cable connected.Do i have to use bridged?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek when I use Bridged connection, my internet does not work in deepin guest machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set up a share on either host machine or the guest. You can use samba for that or NFS ([how to do that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) - it's for Ubuntu, but deepin is ubuntu-based). If you have a local network set up between guest machine and the host of course

Comment: I am gonna try this

Comment: hi, can u provide a youtube video or a tutorial how to setup Samba between guest and host machine. thx

Comment: Just [google that](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+samba+configuration&oq=ubuntu+samba+configuration&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.375j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualBox Shared Folders](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868) would seem to be what you are looking for?

Comment: i tried this but it did not help..

Comment: You need to install the guest additions in your Linux guest before shared folders will work.  It also wouldn't hurt to install the extensions in your Windows host as that gets you things like USB2.0 in your guest.

Your guest must also start the guest modules - some environments will do this automatically and others you have to manually start them.  See, [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Arch_Linux_guests) for an example with Arch Linux (What I'm familiar with).

Comment: I have installed VirtualBox guest addition in deepin guest machine. I have created a bup folder in my D drive of Windows7. I want to share it with the deepin guest. I added it using Shared Folders option in virtualbox. ok . I have also used following command  root@paulMartin-VirtualBox:/home/paulMartin#mkdir host
root@paulMartin-VirtualBox:/home/paulMartin# mount -t vboxsf bup ~/home/host                                                                >>>>>> the second command gives me error "/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory
"